# Html Css and javascript are not detecting page height correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have tried the following:

```
height="window.innerHeight*5"
```

Which produces either 150px tall or 153px tall with no pattern between the two

```
height="window.innerHeight"
```

Which produces the same result

```
and the css 100% attribute
```

Which always produces 153 px rather than one of the two listed above.
I am trying to add an easter egg so it may be hard for you to take this request seriously when you see it.
My site is http://joeybabcock.me , and if you enter the konami code((arrow keys here)type up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, (letters here)b, a) it will open my easter egg which does not cover the whole Page. Currently i have it set to the 100% attribute.

Comment: Link to his source: http://joeybabcock.me/js/loading.js

Comment: `height="window.innerHeight*5"` is a sting. Why the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height of the body and set the element overlay go be fixed with a height/width of 100%. There is no need for JavaScript.

```
body { height:100%; } 
#breadfish {width:100%; height:100%; position: fixed;}
```